# How To Loop Through <li> list with Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, loop, post-thumbnails

Please excuse me for being ignorant. I am currently trying to learn more about PHP and WordPress. This is my first time to post a question on StackExchange.

I found a jQuery plugin for a simple Bootstrap gallery, and I like it. I am trying to make it dynamic so that I can add photos to it using Custom Post Types. I have read the 'The Loop' and 'The Loop In Action' documentation on WordPress.org, as well as scoured the web looking for my answer.

**When I press 'next' on my gallery, it skips every other photo.** It worked fine before I tried to make it dynamic. A regular `<li>` of photos works fine.

I am trying to use `the_post_thumbnail();` as the photo for the gallery.

What am I doing wrong here:

```
  <ul class="row no-gutters">
  <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'photography', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>
  <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <li id="changeJS" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 gal-list thumbnail">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </li>
  <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </ul>
```

If it would help to see my site, it's at: techpresswebdesign.com. If I can't get this to work, I will need to make it a regular static list of photos soon. For what I know, I may be approaching this simple problem completely wrong.

I appreciate your time.

Comment: The fact that you are creating multiple `id="changeJS"`, which is invalid markup, may be causing trouble. But I am guessing. It looks like the WordPress part of this is working.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, s_ha_dum. You're right about me using incorrect markup. I changed the id to a class, and unfortunately I am still having the same problem. Do you think it could have something to do with my functions.php or something? I am baffled.

Comment: "Do you think it could have something to do with my functions.php or something?" -- Why does everyone want to blame WordPress in some obscure way? NO. Something is wrong with your markup vs. what your script expects-- 95% sure.

Comment: I am new to this stuff. I know that sometimes you need to manipulate the functions.php file. I am not trying to blame WordPress. Sorry for the ignorant questions. I will research more and try to clean up my markup.

Comment: My problem is mostly not understanding how WordPress works. I am, in fact, trying to learn. But I thought in the meantime, maybe someone has come across this problem and would know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: As I said before, the WordPress parts seem to work. You are getting the thumbnails inserted and the bootstrap script loads (at least I think the right one is loading). So the problem is with your markup vs. what the script expects. That isn't a WordPress question and answering it means understanding the gallery script that you are using, which is specialized knowledge.

Comment: Yes sir, the bootstrap script loads, otherwise the modal window will not open at all. Thank you so much. At least I know where to look for the problem now, and know that I'm okay on the WordPress side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be useful.

I used it on my own site to display a list of thumbnails.

```
 <?php  
    // check if there's a thumbnail
   if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {

     //show thumbnail
     echo 'get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail' , array('class' => "img-responsive yourClass"));

   } else { 
     //show another image if there's not a thumb 
     echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/MISSING-PHOTOS.jpg">';

    }

   ?>
```

Hope can help you.

Comment: Thank you, sbOk. I am trying to use what I can from this, and no luck so far. But will definitely update if I find an answer.

Comment: @Collin512 I read your question again and had a look at your site. I think this isn't a wordpress's related question but related to jquery, and it's not between my skills yet...but look at line 14 & 38 of your photo-gallery.js . I don't know for what reason..but the next button link to the 2 next images. Try replacing "2" with "1". Anyway there's an updated version of this script.

Comment: That seems extremely reasonable. Unfortunately, I tried that and mixed and matched the 1 and 2 around, and had no luck. I am probably messing things up elsewhere. It's weird, though, since everything works perfectly when static. Only when I tried using CPT did I have issues with the skipping. I really appreciate you looking into this for me.